Disconnect from client in MongoDB in Julia
After connecting a client to Mongoc with Julia (Version 1.11.1). I try to disconnect. I found this :
julia> destroy!(client)
ERROR: UndefVarError: `destroy!` not defined in `Main`
Suggestion: check for spelling errors or missing imports.
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL

Is there a way to disconnect from MongoDB ?
Thank

The function may not be exported. Have you tried MongoDB.destroy!(client) ?

Yes it is good  : Mongoc.destroy!(client)
